# Where to read continuation of Re:Zero anime after episode 24?

Tags: re-zero

I just finished this anime on Crunchyroll, if you have watched it as well, you know how it ends there.

How or where can I see what happens next without waiting for the still possible next season? Also, what chapter of the manga picks up where the anime ends?

Comment: Re:zero is originally a LN. The LNs aren't translated, except volume 1, which was released by Yen Press. Amazon links: [LN Vol1](https://smile.amazon.com/Re-Starting-Another-World-World/dp/0316315303), [(Preorder)LN Vol2](https://smile.amazon.com/Re-light-Starting-Another-World/dp/0316398373/), [(Preorder)LN Vol3](https://smile.amazon.com/Re-light-Starting-Another-World/dp/0316398403/), [Manga Vol1](https://smile.amazon.com/Re-manga-Starting-Another-World/dp/0316315311), [(Preorder) Manga Vol2](https://smile.amazon.com/Re-manga-Starting-Another-World/dp/0316398543)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is: I was mistaken.

Crunchyroll made the series sound (to me) like it was ended 2 weeks ago but the series actually played until this week (not sure yet if there is more coming).

But, thankfully, I was able to see all the episodes up to an actual conclusion.

Answer (score 1):

Episode 24, 25 will cover vol. 9 which will be published in 25th of September 2016. This will mark the end of "Arc 3: The Truth of Zero", follow up by arc 4 that starts with vol. 10 which will start publishing in October.

For the raw/unedited web version (Arc 1 - Arc 6), you can read it on [Shousetsuka ni Narou (Japanese)](http://ncode.syosetu.com/n2267be/).

Comment: Thanks, this is pretty neat actually and google tries hard to translate :) But it is confusing. I guess I'll wait ha ha